# How do I change the value of a string passed by reference to a function?

Tags: c, c-strings

I've been trying for the past hour in utter frustration, but no matter what I try, or look up, I can't find anything that's specific to CStrings.

So I have a function for a library I'm working on that goes like this (edited out the non-relevant bits from it)

```
char *String_set(char **string_one, char *string_two){
 // Tests pointers to check if NULL, return NULL if one is
 free(*string_one); // Free the pointer so as to not cause a leak.
 *string_one = malloc(strlen(string_two) + 1); // Allocate string_one
 memset(*string_one, 0, strlen(string_two) + 1); // Cleans the string
 strcpy(*string_one, string_two); // Copy string_two into string_one by reference
 return *string_one;
}
```

Now, I have also tried NOT freeing the *string_one, and instead reallocating the pointer to hold enough for string_two, THEN clearing it out (with memset), but both have the same result. Either A) Segmentation fault if a string literal was passed, or B) No change if a mutable string is passed.

The kicker (to me) is that I've added quite a few print statements to it to monitor the goings-on of the function, and if anything it confused me even more as I got output like this...

```
//Output before function is called. It outputs info about the string before function
String's value:  
// Initialized it to "", so it's meant to be empty.
String's Memory Address: 0x51dd810
// Inside of function
String's value:  
// Same value
String's Memory Address: 0x51dd810 
// Same memory address
String_Two's Value: "Hello World" 
// What I am attempting to replace it with.
// After operations in function, before return statement
Final String's Value: "Hello World" 
// Gets set
Final String's memory address: 0x51dd950 
// Different address
// After return
String's value:  
// Nothing changed. Even after freeing the contents at memory address?
String's memory address: 0x51dd810 
// Still same memory address ?
```

Then it fails my Unit test because the value did not change as expected. May I get an answer as to why? Now, I'm a bit of a newbie to C, but I figured that anything allocated on the heap is global in scope, hence accessible anywhere. Also modifiable anywhere as well. Why is it that, my changes did not go through at all? Why is it that the value of the string changes in the function but rolls back at the return of it? I know C is pass-by-value, but I figured passing the reference by value would work. How can I properly change the value of a string passed to a function, and what is wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/theif519/08d57a0ce180c43d1df0) of what should be runable code (remove the REVERSE, LOWERCASE, UPPERCASE lines)

Edit2: Updated GIST on mobile, May be some other errors, posted this in a hurry.

Edit3: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/C7SdvB) of the... strangely working build. Strangely, this is also working on both Windows and Linux Virtual Machine, so the problem may not be there specifically... I'm honestly at a lost for words (disregarding the runtime error). I try to compile my project and run the tests over and over, and the code in ideone is word-for-word verbatim (although there's no runtime when I run it, strangely).

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code is fine. http://ideone.com/Ls4gnF Could you include the code implementing your unit test as well?

Comment: Looks good. Show the call.

Comment: You should always check for a NULL returned from malloc!

Comment: The `memset` here does nothing since the allocated memory is the same length of `string_two`, which is subsequently copied into the same space that was just cleared.

Comment: @Deanie  Because after only a billion malllocs, it fails? That said, yes, one should, especially in a library.

Comment: @Deanie While checking for `NULL` returned from `malloc` is generally good practice, worst case, not doing so would only mean that, if the system runs out of available memory, the application would crash and the OS would report an access violation.

Comment: @JimFell: I understand your point, but It's really just lazy programming. #HipsterProgramming

Comment: I wrapped a test harness around the code presented, and it worked fine for me.  The problem is likely in the arguments.  In particular, there will be an issue if `*string_one` is not a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.  For example, the code will break if `*string_one` points to an ordinary array.

Comment: Didn't expect that many replies so quickly. I'll work on making a smaller version of the project. It makes calls other functions (which I had to simplify), and the calls to it are made inside of other functions, but I can replicate the one that's causing this problem. Give me about 10 minutes

Comment: Have to setup Git on my virtual machine, may take a bit longer

Comment: Code seems ok. You may start with isolating the complete compilable example, provided that's very simple to do that. Also in my SO experience the issue is almost always in "edited out the non-relevant bits from it".

Comment: *Even after freeing the contents at memory address?* Yeah. This is the memory after all, right? (hint: nullify all long-living pointers after free unless they're immediately overwritten [by another allocation])

Comment: Updated. In the GIST provided, there will be the bare bones. Although, you have to remove the if statements in copy as the functions aren't included, neither are the macros, they're there to show the gist of what I was getting at with the purpose of the function.

Comment: Plz respond. (´･ω･`) Any problems with the gist?

Comment: I don't understand it. I have both code running, side by side. The one in ideone says freeing string_one and string_two causes a runtime error, so i remove that, it runs fine.It also runs fine on both Linux and Windows. 

However, my project has those exact statements (very little variation, only comments or comment out assertions) and it doesn't work. The memory addresses for the string changes, the value of the string remains the same, and it fails the assertion. I bet there's like 1 small detail I'm missing and it's good and I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full answer, and I'm not sure this isn't becoming code-review, which is actually off-topic on SO. (Viewers please feel free to edit this answer if you find any additional flaws.)

1. String_Utils_concat() has no clean ownership semantics. If `SELECTED(parameter, MODIFY)`, then it returns `string_one` (is literal in test), otherwise `temp` (mallocated). You cannot safely free result unless you remembered the value of `parameter` at time of call.
2. The code is very complex. Consider using `strdup` and `asprintf`.
3. Differences you see on platforms are probably due to different memory management schemes and different behavior of undefined behaviors.
4. Deep coupling of `parameter` is root of all troubles. Code can become less complex just by turning it inside-out. Can't provide a snippet, because all these string_xxx and parameter values, as well as the entire target, feel nonsense to me.

If you need a string library with duplicate/concat facilities, then:

```
char *strdup(const char *s); // already in libc
char *s; asprintf(&s, "%s%s", s1, s2); // already in libc
```

... After aggressive cleaning just for this case, your functions became mostly trivial:

```
// String_Utils_copy() eliminated as strdup() ('parameter' was not used)

char *
String_Utils_set(char **string_one, char *string_two)
{
    free(*string_one);
    return (*string_one = strdup(string_two));
}

char *
String_Utils_concat(char *string_one, char *string_two, int parameter)
{
    char *temp; asprintf(&temp, "%s%s", string_one, string_two);

    if (SELECTED(parameter, MODIFY)) {
        String_Utils_set(&string_one, temp, NONE);
        // i.e. 1) free(string_one);
        //         ^ this probably frees literal
        //      2) string_one = strdup(temp);

        free(temp);
        return string_one;

        // (what was the point at all?)
        // entire thing is same as "return temp" except for freeing literal
    }

    return temp;
}
```

I hope there are some clues now...

Quick edit: as you're already allocating and copying here and there without a reason, I assume you're not in a very tight loop nor constrained otherwise. Then all interfaces should stick with widely-default "get const char *, return char * that should be freed" rule. I.e.

```
char *String_Utils_set(...); // throw it away
char *String_Utils_concat(const char *s1, const char *s2);
char *strdup(const char *s); // already in libc

char *s = String_Utils_concat("Hello, ", "World!");
printf("%s\n", s);
free(s); s = NULL;

char *s = strdup("Hello!");
printf("%s\n", s);
free(s); s = NULL;
```

With that clean and proper interface you may do whatever you meant by `parameter` just in-place, without any headaches.

Comment: Definitely appreciate the answer, but the reason I don't use strdup and other POSIX library functions is because I've heard that they're not very portable, which is what I was aiming for. Of course, if I'm wrong about portability, I'll definitely start using the other available libraries. 

Also, the reasoning behind String_Utils_Copy was to have one function which handles majority of the string modifications (based on parameters).

Comment: @KyleStanly Here we have two issues: 1) code does something wrong and 2) you got the wrong primitive set to solve task. Even if they're not portable, my_strdup() is trivial and my_asprintf() is just a little more effort. Having both of them, you will operate on different abstraction level and be ready to return to issue 1. For now it is completely unclear what purpose of all that code is, if I reduced it correctly.

Comment: @KyleStanly POSIX library functions may not be 100% portable (there are non-POSIX operating systems that exist after all), but that doesn't mean you can't create your own versions of the functions and use them. `strdup` for example is as simple as `size_t n = strlen(s); char *new_s = malloc(++n); if (new_s) memcpy(new_s, old_s, n); return new_s;` (4-5 lines of executable code). You can also just use [Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) to add whatever functions you need, especially for something like `asprintf`.

Comment: You may also implement my_astrcat() instead of my_asprintf(). It's actually done, but with cryptic 'parameter' that should be taken off there.

Comment: @KyleStanly And the last one: if you own the host process and really care about portability and eternity, you may use glib/apr and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Suggest either using `restrict` in `String_Utils_set()` or free the data _after_ the assignment.  This helps with `String_Utils_set(&s, &s)` which otherwise is undefined behavior as code now stands.

Comment: Well, your argument is a rather compelling one. Due to the comment limit, I'll have to split this into multiple comments: 

1) I can agree with getting rid of set entirely, as others have said,and just return the pointer. The only reason I did it was to save myself time by not having to free the pointer. I.E, by having copy and set have a REVERSE parameter, I saw it as a way to lazily get a reverse a string without having to maintain a reference to the new string. Hence, I can't give up copy for strdup, but I can change copy to act like @Chrono's strdup.

Part 2...

Comment: 2) I'll have to agree on not trying to reinvent the wheel. I suppose I tried to implement everything my own way, and sadly failed. A huge chunk of motivation for this process was to learn and to experiment, and while I've already attempted that, I can't say I've got anything against implementing already well-tested library functions. I was gonna say something else, but I forgot. Ah well.

Comment: @KyleStanly This is a great training indeed. Few more libs and you'll clearly see why we have KISS, SPOT, YAGNI and DRY.

Comment: @user3125367 Honestly, I did have a few more libraries coming. I had planned a Networking, Files and I/O, Concurrency, and then normal generic data structures. I figured that if I handled everything once, then it'd make creating projects that used these a lot easier in the future since most of the work would already be done... or at least look good on a resume.

Comment: @KyleStanly You're actually not failed – handling char** consciously is already a great effort. Keep trying and you'll get the feeling of what is a good conception and what isn't. This comes only with a long distance, and that is what C is about. Good luck!